Create shared photo album online and give permissions to owner via a link
I'm looking to create a shared photo album online and give a link to other people so they can upload photos. I want them to own the folder and permission to share and feel safe with privacy. Ideally, I could create a Google photo album, create a shared permanent link and hand over ownership. I would also like it if you didn't need an account to upload photos, you just needed the link. Any ideas on how to do this?
I have looked up most sharing sites like Google Photos, Dropbox, one Drive, and none of them quite work for the intended purpose.
